# Call variable within PHP PDO object result

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am using PHP and PDO to get data from databases, but i have a little problem trying to mix the object with a language variable.

There are diferent languages, so i have to use a variable with a language, please keep in mind there could be any language, that´s why i have to use the variable.

The query works perfect, it gets values from DB with the language, BUT it can´t be echoed.

Please help!

```
$language = en;

// Do select from DB
$sql_query = $db_data->prepare("SELECT id, image, ".$language."_description FROM table");
$sql_query->execute();

while($data = $sql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $data->image; // works perfect!
    echo $data->$language."_description"; // this does not work, this is what i need
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't want this:

```
echo ($data->$language) . ("_description");
```

... but this:

```
echo $data->{$language."_description"};
```

Parenthesis have been added for dramatic purposes. The feature is called [variable properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

When you read a method property that doesn't exist you can get a `Undefined property` notice to easily spot the error. Since you don't, I suggest you review your error reporting settings.

Additionally, you can use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) to inspect variables.

Comment: Wow! You answered amazingly fast! thanks a lot for your knowlegde, the brackets were the answer: echo $data->{$language."_description"};

Comment: Just added a link I forgot, you know, for the dirty details.